# How to implement the idea of a realtime python api connected to an ios app?

Tags: python, swift, api, real-time

to know the basic idea of what I'm doing, I have an IOS application that i would like to connect to my custom Ubuntu 16.04 server and have it get number value updates in real-time via a python API.

I don't know what methods should i use, like a web socket or request updates manually at time intervals from swift client... but I kind of have an idea that when the app detects a value change in the server, I would update it on my app.

Simply put, i want real-time updates of a value from my server, and i don't know how to implement it, can someone give me an idea on how to implement it? code isn't necessary, just what methods and concepts are good enough for real-time updates?

P.S: If you want more clarification, please dont hesitate to ask, i'll be happy to give you more details

**UPDATE**

So I've decided to use the pusher from pusher.com that lets my server send events to the pusher APIs and thus receiving them on my ios app by PusherSwift!

Comment: Don't poll. Have your server send push notifications.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh i like the sound of that, never heard about it before, will definitely check it out, thanks!

Comment: @rmaddy I've implemented a python pusher that will let my ios app receive events automatically, thank you for mentioning that concept :D